Deploying backpack for Laravel project in a production environment
I am developing a Backpack for Laravel project locally using wamp, visual studio code, and git. In the local environment everything works correctly.
When I try to deploy the Backpack for Laravel project in a VPS, it doesn't work. That is, when I browse to the URL of the project: https://example.com, I see the Laravel page of a new project. When I browse to  https://example.com/admin, I get: "The requested URL was not found on this server", instead of the usual login page of backpack.
These are the steps I followed to deploy the project:

Clone from GitHub

Make relevant changes in .env:


2.1 Change APP_ENV from local to production,
2.2 Change APP_URL,
2.3 Change database credentials

Run migrations

make sure that all the permissions are correct in all directories and subdirectories of the system

composer install

Repeat step 2



Hey there, can you check in your production vendor folder if you have backpack/crud there ?

Hi there. Thanks for the answer. Yes I do.
